# create an automatic update RSS feed out of .txt file

Tags: php

i have a .txt file consist of number of text lines, i want some PHP script to create an RSS feed and update it with line by line out of the .txt file every some amount of time, say 2 minutes [say, i have a .txt file consists of 100 text lines, the script will create an RSS Feed and update it every 2 minutes with an text line in order so it will be line N1, line N2, line N2,....., line N100 then it stop updating the RSS feed], i hope i made it clear, is it doable, (i'm not good in PHP or XML programming, i searched all over the internet for something like this but i couldn't find any solutions, i hope you can help me) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would take around half an hour to an hour to code and test.

The idea is:

1. use file_get_contents to get the file into a variable
2. split the file on "\n" and store the resultant array into a variable
3. use `header` to set the mime type to the one for RSS feeds
4. echo the start of the RSS feed
5. foreach line of the array, split on commas, if it is a csv and put each bit into a variable
6. echo the relevant XML for each line (read RSS spec to find out
   what it is)
7. echo the end of the RSS feed

Then submit to the [RSS validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) and tweak until it's valid

Then  use cron to run the file regularly

This would be a very good place to learn some PHP – follow what I've said, and it won't be too painful!

Comment: thanks for your response, it seems a little hard to do, but i will try to do it, thanks again.